# Why aren't my young chili plants growing?

Tags: vegetables, chili

I planted chili pepper plants about four weeks ago along with other vegetables. All the vegetables are growing, even the seeds that I planted, but the peppers have grown slightly but seem to be at a standstill now. They are only about 2 inches, they are green and look healthy, but no growth. What do I need to do?

Comment: Some pictures would help.  Also, if you can update your question with your watering schedule and soil conditions (when was it last fertilized, etc.) that would be helpful.  Also, are the different vegetables growing too close to each other?

Comment: Welcome to the group deb! This is a well-written question; we just need a few more details, in addition to what @JStorage asked. Have you ever successfully grown these types of peppers in that spot? What's the temperature range where you live? How much daily sun/shade do they get? The more we know, the more we can help you. Just [edit] the information into your question. Check out our [help] to learn how the site works. [Ask] is a great place to start. We look forward to getting to know you better!

Comment: What is the temperature?  Is it consistent?  Peppers are heat loving plants.  Just one cold night will set them back.

Comment: I stunted my pepper plants that way one year by adding too much nitrogen to their soil. Peppers are pickier about that than tomatoes.